# Good reference for number of permutations for a simple test?

Tags: sample-size, permutation-test

I have two vectors of 100 real values each.  I would like to use a permutation test for a few things such as the correlation of the two vectors.  I would use the approach of keeping one vector stationary and then permuting the other in relation to it and then calculate the statistic of interest (such as correlation) on the permutation.  I have found some guidance for the number iterations for things like bootstrapping, but have not found a general guide for permutations of a simple and similar type.  I have code to run the permutation and it is very fast.  I am tempted to just run 1,000,000 and have be self-evidently large, but it would be nice to have a reference to justify this, and I haven't found one.

Can anyone give direction to one?

Comment: Unless someone has a better idea, I just found something.  You can calculate 95% ci on the permutation using the p value as a binomial proportion.  The 95% ci is very small for a 0.05 p-value if you use 1,000,000 permutations.  I can just show that.  This is found in Ernst, M.D. 2004. Permutation methods: a basis for exact inference. Statistical Science 19: 676-685.

Comment: That's how I usually work out how big a sample to take for a randomization test - to work out how accurate I want my p-values and then get the original number of permutations from that. (If it turns out to be close to as many as doing all possible permutations, I do that instead - once or twice I caught myself randomly sampling a million permutations when the total number of distinct permutations of the data was smaller than that. I try not to make that mistake any more.)

Comment: Why not write up your comment as an answer? You're free to answer your own question.

Comment: Rules of thumb are of course crude, not fully general, and to be taken with a healthy grain of salt, but many researchers in various fields have suggested that performing 500-1000 iterations often works well. I suspect this is because if you need more iterations to discern differences then your effect size is likely so small the significance (or lack thereof) does not matter anyway.